# Image type UNKNOWN with PDFBox and JPEG 2000 sample

Tags: java, pdfbox, jpeg2000

I've taken a sample *JPEG 2000* from the [fnord examples page](https://www.fnordware.com/j2k/jp2samples.html).

However, when I try to add that image to the PDF:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDImageXObject pdImage = pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(
   "samples/relax.jp2", document);
PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(pageWidth, pageHeight));
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, matrix);
contentStream.close();
```

I get the exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image type UNKNOWN not
> supported: relax.jp2
> at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(PDImageXObject.java:313)

The PDFBox dependencies that I have in Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.16</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or there is some problem with PDFBox and/or the samples that I'm using?

Other Apache library, [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/), detects this sample file MIME type as `image/jp2`:

```
TikaConfig tika = new TikaConfig();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
MediaType mimetype = tika.getDetector().detect(
     TikaInputStream.get(new FileInputStream("samples/relax.jp2"), metadata);
```

Comment: What you could do is to read the file into a BufferedImage. Currently PDFBox does not support direct usage of jp2 files. One could write code for it, but jp2 is not a common format. So the question is, do you have a real application that needs to use these files directly (i.e. without conversion to BufferedImage) or did you just try a few images from everywhere for fun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PDFBox's [API documentation](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromFileByContent-java.io.File-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-):

> `createFromFileByContent()`
> The following file types are supported: jpg, jpeg, tif, tiff, gif, bmp and png.

Looking into the source code, what gets called inside `createFromFileByContent()` is their own check for known *file types*, independent from the underlying libraries, the detection code looks like this: [FileTypeDetector.java](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.3/source-code/org/apache/pdfbox/util/filetypedetector/FileTypeDetector.java).

This check does not recognize [*JPEG 2000*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000).

Actually `createFromFileByExtension()` might be a better bet:

```
if ("gif".equals(ext) || "bmp".equals(ext) || "png".equals(ext)) {
    BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(file);
    return LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, bim);
}
```

As long as you pretend you have a *GIF*, *BMP* or *PNG* and your `ImageIO` supports *JPEG 2000*, this might somewhat work (not tested).

Comment: Thank you. It really looks like when I'm able to recognize format with Tika, I should rename the input file according to my own rules (like image/jp2 and image/x-jbig2 are .jpg) and then use createFromFileByExtension. It looks like a bug to pdfbox.