# Java PDFBox - Check if Page contains jpeg2000

Tags: java, pdfbox, jpeg2000

i want to extract the first Page of a PDF-File as an Image.
With the following lines it works just fine:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdf);
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
BufferedImage img = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 72, ImageType.ARGB);
```

BUT, if the PDF-File contains a jpeg2000 Image on this Page, i get the following Error in my logfile 
"Cannot read JPEG2000 image: Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) Image I/O Tools are not installed"

Google told me i can use these Dependencys to fix it

- jai-imageio-core
- jai-imageio-jpeg2000

but since its unclear if its allowed to use this in a regular Application i dont want to use them.

So my real Question is:

**Is there a way to check if there's a jpeg2000 on this page?**

Im using pdfbox-Version: 2.0.19

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481280/image-type-unknown-with-pdfbox-and-jpeg2000-sample). Hope that it will be helpful.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Read the license instead. If you still want to know whether there are jpeg2000 images, have a look at the source code of ExtractImages.java.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i tryed to understand what im allowed to do, but its soo unclear...

Comment: If you're an individual on his/her own, or just something inside your company, then it's probably no problem. If you want to sell the software, then there may be rules that you have to follow.

Comment: It is an existing Software Product, so its not for myself unfortunatly

Comment: Then clarify this with your legal department or get legal advice. The alternative would be to ship a viewer that would sometimes show empty pages. That would be weird.